# SSIS load column number(precision,scale)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

Hi I have a SSIS package which I use to load the monthly data. Every month vendor send us data in same format but they have changed this month. the price column in my MS sql server database is `PRICE decimal(7,2)` but client sent us data having `price=210000.0000`. I rounded to two decimal but I still can not load data. Please help!!!

Comment: why not replying to the answer provided. I am waiting for a feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a derived column transformation with the following expression

```
(DT_NUMERIC,7,2)ROUND([Column],2)
```